# How to get multiple years Y-axis data from a single file on the same plot?

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I have gas meter readings over three years which I'm trying to graph in R, to highlight the changing daily usage over the months in a year, and to compare different years' usage.

Data sample:

```
Date,Gas  
02/01/2010,4460.9  
13/01/2010,4543  
04/02/2010,4656  
16/02/2010,4733  
07/03/2010,4842  
26/03/2010,4933.8
```

I can calculate the average daily usage from the periodic readings, and plot the whole of the data across several years as a single data series:

```
A <- read.table("energy.csv", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, sep=',')
A$Dates <- as.Date(A$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
for (j in 2:length(A$Gas)) {
  A$GasDiff[j-1] = A$Gas[j] - A$Gas[j-1]
}
plot(A$Dates, A$GasDiff, type="o", lty=1, pch=20, ylab="Daily Consumption",
     main="Gas Consumption")
```

But I can't figure out how to get R to automatically split the data into different ?frames? for each year, so that I can plot separate lines for each year.  I can manually create different input files with just the data for each year, but it's inelegant, and will need the code changed every year.

I'm sure it's a simple question, but I've stared at manuals, and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 14):

There's no need to split the data into data-frames by year; you can use the `ggplot2` package quite easily to differentiate the plots by year. First I'll make up some data:

```
dts <- as.Date("20050101", '%Y%m%d') + seq(0,1000,15)
A <- data.frame( Dates = dts, Gas = 4000 + cumsum(abs( rnorm(length(dts), 100, 30))))
```

Next I'll add two columns to `A`: `DayOfYear` which is the "day-number" within the year, and the `GasDiff` column (same as yours but generated more easily, *with no loops*!):

```
A <- transform( A,               
               Year = format(Dates, '%Y'),
               DayOfYear = as.numeric( format(Dates, '%j')),
               GasDiff = c(diff( Gas ),NA))
```

Next we use `ggplot2` to first plot all the years one after the other, but with different colors:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(A, aes(Dates, GasDiff)) + geom_line( aes(colour = Year))
```

which gives you this:
[image]

Alternatively you can plot the different years in a vertical grid:

```
ggplot(A, aes(DayOfYear, GasDiff)) + geom_line( )  + facet_grid(Year ~ .)
```

and you get this:
[image]

***UPDATE:*** A third way is to plot all the years on the same plot with different colors/points, which may be useful if you are looking for seasonal patterns (but looks bad in my case because I made up random data).

```
ggplot(A, aes(DayOfYear, GasDiff)) + 
  geom_line( aes(colour = Year) )  + 
  geom_point( aes(shape = Year))
```

[image]

Comment: Try ggsave(), as in ggsave("/tmp/image.png", width=5, height=4, dpi=72) -- I use it all the time on my Mac instead of saving as PDF, converting, uploading, etc.

Comment: @Jeffrey Ah yes of course, that's the way to do it, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Prasad - that was quick, and so helpful, giving me just what I'm after.

Comment: @Jeffrey, I will also check out ggsave as you suggest.

Comment: Updated the plots using `ggsave( '*.png')`

Comment: much better! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 8):

Here are the plots corresponding to Prasad's ggplot examples (1) done using `xyplot` in lattice.  (2) After that we show how to do it using `xyplot.zoo` from the zoo package and then (3) we show how to do each yet again using the `plot.zoo` which uses the zoo package's  classic graphics facilities.

In each of these cases we also show a 4th style which is based on `xblocks`.

First lets repeat Prasad's setup:

```
dts <- as.Date("20050101", '%Y%m%d') + seq(0,1000,15)
A <- data.frame( Dates = dts, Gas = 4000 + cumsum(abs( rnorm(length(dts), 100, 30))))

A <- transform( A,               
               Year = format(Dates, '%Y'),
               DayOfYear = as.numeric( format(Dates, '%j')),
               GasDiff = c(diff( Gas ),NA))
```

Now lets try using lattice

```
library(lattice) # xyplot
library(latticeExtra) # layer_, panel.xblocks
library(gridExtra) # grid.arrange
library(RColorBrewer) # brewer.pal

png("png1.png")
p1 <- xyplot(GasDiff ~ Dates, group = Year, A, type = "l",
    par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col = 1:nlevels(A$Year))),
    auto.key = list(lines = TRUE, points = FALSE))

p2 <- xyplot(GasDiff ~ DayOfYear | Year, A, type = "l", layout = c(1, 3))

p3 <- xyplot(GasDiff ~ DayOfYear, A, group = Year, type = "l",
    auto.key = list(lines = TRUE, points = FALSE))

# and here is another style:

myPalette <- brewer.pal(nlevels(A$Year), "Set3")
p4 <- xyplot(GasDiff ~ Dates, A, type = "l", col = 1) + 
    layer_(panel.xblocks(A$Dates, myPalette[A$Year]))

grid.arrange(nrow = 2, p1, p2, p3, p4)
dev.off()
```

This gives these 4 plots:

[image]

and now lets repeat this using using zoo in conjunction with the lattice and the other packages:

```
png("png2.png")
library(zoo)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra) # layer_, panel.xblocks
library(gridExtra) # grid.arrange
library(RColorBrewer) # brewer.pal

z <- with(A, zoo(GasDiff, Dates))
year <- format(time(z), "%Y")

# split years into separate columns and plot
P1 <- xyplot(do.call("merge", split(z, year)), screen = 1, col = 1:3)

# split years into separate columns and use day.of.year as time
day.of.year <- function(x) as.numeric(format(x, "%j"))
zz <- read.zoo(A[c(1, 5, 3)], FUN = day.of.year, split = 3)
colnames(zz) <- unique(year)
P2 <- xyplot(na.approx(zz, na.rm = FALSE))

P3 <- xyplot(na.approx(zz, na.rm = FALSE), screen = 1, col = 1:3, auto.key = TRUE)

pal <- brewer.pal(nlevels(factor(year)), "Set3")
P4 <- xyplot(z, screen = 1) + layer_(panel.xblocks(time(z), pal[factor(year)]))

grid.arrange(nrow = 2, P1, P2, P3, P4)
dev.off()
```

Here is the output:

[image]

A third set of ways is to use classic graphics with zoo where we use the same `z`, `zz` and `pal` calculated above:

```
library(zoo)
library(RColorBrewer) # brewer.pal

png("png3a.png")
plot(do.call("merge", split(z, year)), screen = 1, col = 1:3)
dev.off()
png("png3b.png")
plot(na.approx(zz, na.rm = FALSE))
dev.off()
png("png3c.png")
plot(na.approx(zz, na.rm = FALSE), screen = 1, col = 1:3)
legend("topleft", colnames(zz), lty = 1, col = 1:3, bty = "n")
dev.off()
png("png3d.png")
plot(z, type = "n")
xblocks(time(z), pal[factor(year)])
lines(z)
dev.off()
```

and here is the output

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @G.G, that's lots of new ways to improve my charting output. Suddenly the lattices etc. don't seem so daunting.

Comment: G, shouldn't the above na.approx(zz) be na.approx(zz, na.rm = FALSE)?

Comment: @bill_080, yes you are right. I will fix that.  (We only lose a couple of points off the beginning if we don't do it.)